# vanilla javascript: element.close() not working on element

Tags: javascript

This is a Sudoko generator I'm programming in vanilla javascript:

[Fiddle with code](http://jsfiddle.net/mles/p40oahkd/4/)

[Nicer looking full screen fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mles/p40oahkd/4/embedded/result/)

If you click on one of the fields, a popup will be shown with 3x3 fields from 1 to 9. The problem is this popup can't be closed anymore, although I'm applying the close dialog.

The code how I'm generating the **Sudoku board**:

```
// create sudoku
function tableCreate() {
    var body = document.getElementsByClassName("frame")[0];
    var containerDiv = body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
    containerDiv.className = 'container';

    // create single cells with numbers
    function createInnnerCells(parent, xx, yy) {
        for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
            for (var y = 1; y <= 3; y++) {
                var abc = function () {
                    var div = parent.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))

                    var X = y+yy;
                    var Y = x+xx;
                    var id = 'x' + [X] + 'y' + [Y];

                    var cellValue = sudoku[X][Y]['value'] || '';

                    div.style.background = sudoku[X][Y]['background'] || 'white'
                    div.className = 'cell';
                    div.id = id;

                    var popover = createDialog(id);

                    popover.onclick = function() {
                        popover.close();
                    };

                    div.onclick = function() {
                        popover.show();
                    };

                    div.appendChild(popover);
                    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellValue));
                };
                abc();
            }
        }
    }

    // create big cells for 3x3 single cells
    for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i+=3) {
        for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j+=3) {
            var div = containerDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
            div.className = 'block';
            createInnnerCells(div, i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I apply the close() function to each cell:

```
popover.onclick = function() {
  popover.close();
};
```

The code how I create the **popup**:

```
    // create dialog
    function createDialog(position){
        var dialog = document.createElement('dialog');
        dialog.id ='window_'+ position;

        var dialogblock = dialog.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        dialogblock.className = 'dialogblock';
        for (var z = 1; z <= 9; z++) {
            var div = dialogblock.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));

            div.className = 'dialogcell';
            div.id = position + 'z'+ z;
            div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(position));
        }

        dialog.onclick = function() {
            dialog.close();
        };

        return dialog;
    }
```

I applied the close() dialog here as well

```
dialog.onclick = function() {
  dialog.close();
};
```

I don't know why show() is working, but close() not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOM events bubble up the DOM through its parents.  In your code, the `dialog` is a child of `div`.  Therefore, a `click` event happens on `dialog` and then again on `div` which means you're closing and then opening the dialog.

You can stop the propagation of the event by using `event.stopPropagation`.

You can change your code like this:

```
popover.onclick = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  popover.close();
};
```

and

```
dialog.onclick = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  dialog.close();
};
```

modified your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p40oahkd/9/

Comment: Wicked. That also explains why I was able to close the popup when assigning the close() to a single `<button></button>`. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

There's no method `close()` on the element you are trying to hide. You should either do `element.style.display = "none"` if you need to hide. Or do the following:

```
dialog.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.remove();
});
```

Check out this [edit to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p40oahkd/5/).

Comment: That's what I thought, but: [Chrome has this method in the HTMLDialogElement prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement)